# What does `ruby -e "$(curl url)"` means?

Tags: ruby

What does this line from [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) mean?

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

I understand `-e` will include ruby code in command but I don't get the `$()` part. What's the dollar sign bracket doing here?

And very importantly, where can I find the documentation for this?

Answer (score 10):

$(...) is Bash [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution). It happens before the command is executed; it executes the command inside the parentheses and substitutes its output. For example,

```
echo "There are $(ls | wc -l) files in this directory"
```

will first execute `ls | wc -l` which will output e.g. `17`; then `echo "There are 17 files in this directory"`.

`curl` is a command-line utility that fetches the contents at an URL and outputs that content, by default. Thus, `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)` will first download the contents of https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install , then substitute it into the command line as the parameter of the `-e` option. Ruby will then execute it as Ruby code.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is unrelated to Ruby; it is a *shell* question. Assuming that the shell running this command is either bash or ksh or Zsh, these shells replace an expression of the form `$(COMMAND)` by the standard output of this command. Hence in your case, the standard output of the `curl` command is executed as Ruby code.

Comment: The `$()` part isn't related to Ruby, the question as a whole is.